# Flipping iPhone orientation reloads viewcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a viewcontroller with an SKview (I'm working with spritekit) inside of it and every time I change the orientation of the phone (from landscape one way to landscape another way or vise versa) it reloads the viewcontroller as if I had just opened the app (the viewcontroller is the initial one).

Is there a work around for it?

I can't seem to find anyone having the same problem.

Code:

http://pastie.org/8669630

Comment: Could you post your view controller code and relevant app delegate code. It should not reload every time orientation is changed.

Comment: @DobroćudniTapir there you go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting up your SKView in [viewWillLayoutSubview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews) which gets called every time device is rotated (view frame changes).

Which is good, because view will have correct dimensions, but you should place some var to know should you set up the view again. For example BOOL sceneSetUp

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    if(!self.sceneSetUp){
    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    //skView.showsFPS = YES;


    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * startScene = [StartViewController sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    startScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    SKScene * scene = [gameViewController sceneWithSize:skView.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:startScene];
    //[skView presentScene:scene];
    self.sceneSetUp = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: In almost all cases it suffices to simply check for: if(skView.scene == nil) {..}